# Alternative ways of saying "white-labeled"?

Tags: single-word-requests, political-correctness

In software engineering, there has been a movement towards ensuring that language is more inclusive and culturally sensitive.

For example, I've been in companies that now use the word "main" instead of "master" branch, and allow-list/block-list instead of "white-list"/"black-list".

Are there synonyms for the concept of "[white-labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-label_product)"?

A compound word or phrase would be acceptable. What's important to me is that people will understand what I mean. I'd like to be able to omit the explanatory line below in parentheses.

Example sentence:

"If I could go back and engineer that project again, I'd consider building it in a **white-labeled** way. (Instead of everything being designed just for myself, the system would also support additional customers.)"

My understanding of "private label" is more like when a grocery store wants to profit from branding a certain product but would prefer to buy and re-label and existing product. With "private label", it seems like there is a 1-to-1 relationship between product and new label. This doesn't quite fit my feeling of how I've heard "white-labeled", which implies more like "the core product is already built, and it can serve unlimited companies who each can pay to attach their logo to it."

Comment: I think trying to replace every instance of “black” or “white” misses the point. A white label is blank so it can be customized. I don’t understand how that usage is problematic when compared to something more obvious like “black list/white list” or “master/slave”. A “black label” variation of something is usually really exclusive/luxurious instead of “generic” like a white label something. Would you clarify the problem with “white label” please?

Comment: @ColleenV I agree that words like "master bathroom" are in the most dire need of being replaced because of the obvious original meaning, but I wouldn't be surprised if white/black words in general can be problematic even when not immediately obviously so to every listener. I just want to be proactive and thinking about it.

Comment: If you don’t know how a term could be offensive, isn’t it a bit presumptuous to try to “fix” it? What if the term you decide on is also problematic in ways you don’t know? What about the other terms that include a stereotyped skin color?

Comment: @Ryan, I'm not sure [the history of master bedroom is obvious](https://www.etymonline.com/word/master), given that it first appeared in 1919. It's as problematic as master-key or master plan.

Comment: @ColleenV I think there is a certain wisdom to shying away from potentially offensive phrases, even when the offense is only perceived due to misunderstanding. *Tar baby,* for instance, has no particular racial history, but enough people seem to perceive it that way as to caution its use. Same with *niggard.* Though, both of these terms are already uncommon enough that it is quite easy to go without using them, unlike the numerous white/black terms, or the various uses of *master.*

Comment: @GArthurBrown You’ll get no argument from me. Language is for communication, and if a term is likely to communicate a connotation you don’t intend, it should be avoided. I don’t think it’s wise to assume every use of “white” could be offensive in every context. What word shall we limit to only one context next? Is “curly” parsley offensive? Equating “white label” with language like “black list” and conflating “master bedroom” with “master/slave” is unintentionally mocking legitimate concerns. I can’t think of the exact word I’m looking for unfortunately. headache :( patronizingly trivializing

Comment: @ColleenV It is interesting that the white/black label case actually carries the exact opposite connotations from what we'd expect. I hadn't thought of that till you pointed it out.

Comment: https://www.johnniewalker.com/en-us/our-whisky/johnnie-walker-labels/black-label/

Comment: Johnnie Walker link was dead so here's Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20211022003319/https://www.johnniewalker.com/en-us/our-whisky/johnnie-walker-labels/black-label/

Answer (score 5):

I think

Unbranded or in the UK, unbadged

Would be easily understood.

un·brand·ed
/ˌənˈbrandəd/

> 1. (of a product) not bearing a brand name.
>    "unbranded computer systems"
> 2. (of livestock) not branded with the owner's mark.

Definitions from Oxford Languages

Comment: I chose this option. It also has the advantage that "unbranded" is a single word, so you don't have to worry about camel case usage (i.e. should it be "whiteLabel" or "whitelabel"?)

Answer (score 5):

[Private label](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_label) is what I have always known one company making a product to be sold by another company to be called.

> Private label products are those manufactured by one company for sale under another company's brand.

Private label products are often the same as the one marketed by a parent brand, with a different brand label attached. While there are also companies who specialize private label products to a buyer's desires, often they already have the product and sell it to multiple buyers with different labels.

> In 2007, there was a recall in the United States of more than 60 million cans of pet food sold under more than 100 brand names made by Menu Foods.

This means that over 100 brands are getting the same product with different private labeling. In other words, the core product is already built and each company pays to attach their logo to it.

Comment: private label is what results when an unbranded product is later given a brand by a third part.

Comment: Yet the companies who produce them are called [private label manufacturers](https://www.ecommerceceo.com/private-label-manufacturers/).

Comment: True, they are producing *for* private label companies. As the product leaves their factory it is unbranded.  It gets branded and resold as a private labeled product.

Comment: ["Private label products are those manufactured by one company for sale under another company's brand."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_label) ["A white-label product is a product or service produced by one company (the producer) that other companies (the marketers) rebrand to make it appear as if they had made it."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-label_product)

Comment: thanks - that clears it up. If the product leaves the factory of company A with the brand of company B it is a private label product, If it leaves with no brand it is a white label or unbranded product. That unbranded product might later be branded and resold as a private label product.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Not quite that simple. [This company uses them interchangeably](https://intrepidsourcing.com/solutions/white-label-package/). They both involve the producer modifying the branding and packaging for the marketer. The primary difference seems to be that Private Label deals can involve customization while White Label deals never do.

Answer (score 3):

If "white label" is meant to denote that the label is "blank", then "Blank Label" could just as easily be used as a replacement and be more clear.

Comment: Blank also means white in some languages (with all the connotations of white in English. So it depends if you're worried about connotations for non-English speakers (given that English is now a global language).